# Middle mouse transform like in Maya (no gizmo interaction)

Tags: 3d-view, transforms

While I am getting more and more comfortable with the interface in blender I am missing out one thing:
The way you can edit e.g. vertices in maya by selecting and then middle mouse drag *anywhere* on the screen.
In blender afaik I can only either select and then every time hit the g key, select and move only one vertex with tweak or having to use the movement gizmo when in move mode (meaning I have to hit it with the mouse).
That means i have to click or keypress one more time after selection compared to maya, where I was able to select and then middle mouse drag to move the selection.

Would be awesome if that was somehow available in blender as well.

Comment: Hello :). This isn't the right place for [feature requests](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/), but you can set-up your shortcuts any way you want. So, what is your question again? :)

Comment: I just wanted to know if that exists, not create a feature request. :)

Comment: As I said, you can change most shortcuts in Blender's preferences :)